# How to get the value of `@value` in a json array whose `@name` is `dbUrl` using jq?

Tags: json, jq

The following `test.json` file is converted from an xml file with [xq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```
{
  "project": {
    "@basedir": ".",
    "property": [
      {
        "@environment": "env"
      },
      {
        "@name": "foo",
        "@value": "bar"
      },
      {
        "@name": "aaa",
        "@value": "bbb"
      },
      {
        "@name": "dbUrl",
        "@value": "123.123.123.123"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I get `123.123.123.123` using `dbUrl` with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

Please don't tell me to use `jq '.project.property[3]["@value"]' test.json` to get `123.123.123.123`.

Because `{"@name": "dbUrl", "@value": "123.123.123.123"}` is not guaranteed to appear on the 4th position of `property`.

For example:

```
{
  "project": {
    "@basedir": ".",
    "property": [
      {
        "@environment": "env"
      },
      {
        "@name": "foo",
        "@value": "bar"
      },
      {
        "@name": "dbUrl",
        "@value": "123.123.123.123"
      },
      {
        "@name": "aaa",
        "@value": "bbb"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In this case, `jq '.project.property[3]["@value"]' test.json` doesn't return `123.123.123.123`. It returns `bbb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to look into a specific index, just use the `select()` expression do that for you, which will return the `@name` containing `dbUrl` and return its `@value`

```
jq --raw-output '.project.property[] | select(."@name"=="dbUrl") | ."@value"'
```

Since the fields `@name` and `@value` have a special character `@` present, you need to access them inside quotes.

[jqplay - URL](https://jqplay.org/s/eq8dsEpYee)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the values of "@value" corresponding to "@name" being "dbUrl":

```
.. | objects | select(.["@name"] == "dbUrl") | .["@value"]
```

Here I've used the `.["KEYNAME"]` form for accessing the value corresponding to "KEYNAME" as that is more robust than `.KEYNAME`.